# Multiplying both sides of matrix equation by inverse

Tags: matrices

Say I have the following relationship between matrices:

$AB = A^{2} + 2A$

If I multiply both sides of the equation by $A^{-1}$ is the resulting equation equivalent, meaning it doesn't change the values of A or B? So for example:

$(A^{-1})AB = (A^{-1})A^{2} + (A^{-1})(2A)$

And thus get:

$B = A + 2I$

Is this correct?

EDIT: Assume A is a square invertible matrix.

Comment: How do you know $A$ is invertible?

Comment: Assume A is a square invertible matrix.

Comment: Then yes, it's fine. Interesting question: Is that assumption necessary, or can you solve the problem without it?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I'm going to guess not...although I can't give a mathematical reason why.

Comment: Actually it is. I was thinking of a different situation, sorry. Note that $A$ doesn't have to be invertible as $A = O$ satisfies the equation for any $B$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I wonder in a case where AB=2A if it matters. When you multiply both sides by A^-1 you get B=2I so B isn't dependent on A.

Comment: What you have done is found what $B$ must be if $A$ is invertible, but again, $A = O$ is a valid solution and there may be others corresponding to non-invertible $A$. Consider instead the equation $AB = A^2 + 2A + I$. As there is an $A^2$ term, $A$ must be square. Furthermore, we can rewrite the equation as $A(B - A - 2I) = I$, so $A$ is invertible with inverse $A^{-1} = B - A - 2I$. This was the situation I was thinking about in my initial comment. The key difference is the identity matrix's presence (or lack thereof).

Comment: Interesting...I never thought about it that way. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

Provided an inverse exists multiplying by an inverse matrix preserves the relation you started with. This is analogous to dividing two sides of a relation. For example if $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$:

$xy=x^{2}+2x$

Provided that $x\neq0$ then:

$\frac{xy}{x}=\frac{x^{2}}{x}+\frac{2x}{x}$

$y=x+2$.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure if they worked like standard algebra variables in these case or not.

Comment: You're welcome. It works similar to standard algebra but there are more ways to not have an inverse since there are zero divisors.